# Some Problems About Swift Function

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

## Got A Problem With Swift Function

I wrote a function, and I called it within `.onAppear {}`. But it returned a value before executing the main body of the function. I'm new to Swift, and I cannot finger it out.

Here is the function definition:

```
func getUnapprovedCourses(account: String) -> [Course] {
        
        print("===== [1] Main body of the function ===== \n")
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var coursesArray: [Course] = []
        
        db.collection("temp_courses").whereField("teach_by", isEqualTo: account)
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    do {
                        let singleCourse: Course = try document.data(as: Course.self)
                        print("===== [2] Append an element ===== \n")
                        coursesArray.append(singleCourse)
                    } catch {
                        print("Place A error... [ FirestoreManager.swift -> UserManager -> getUnapprovedCourses ]")
                    }
                    // print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                }
            }
        
        print("===== [3] Return an array ===== \n")
        return coursesArray
    }
```

And I called the function in this way

```
.onAppear {
            getCouresesInfo()
        }

// getCoursesInfo()

func getCoursesInfo() {
    let userManager = UserManager()    
    print("===== [0] Call the function ===== \n")      
    coursesArray = userManager.getUnapprovedCourses(account: account)
}
```

And here are the results printed in the console:

```
===== [0] Call the function ===== 

===== [1] Main body of the function ===== 

===== [3] Return an array ===== 

===== [2] Append an element =====
```

It returned first and then appended elements. I hope someone can help me out. :) Thx.

I wish it could append some elements to that array `coursesArray`, then return the value.

Comment: db.collection method works async . you need to add a completion handler or add a new async-await function that has db.collection{...} operations

Answer (score 2):

your `.....getDocuments() {...}` is an asynchronous function. You have to
understand how they work. It means you have to wait until the results are available before you can use them.

Currently, your `return coursesArray` gets executed immediately with an empty array.

Use a `completion` handler, as shown in the example code.

```
 // --- here
 func getUnapprovedCourses(account: String, completion: @escaping([Course]) -> Void) {
     print("===== [1] Main body of the function ===== \n")
     
     let db = Firestore.firestore()
     var coursesArray: [Course] = []
     
     db.collection("temp_courses").whereField("teach_by", isEqualTo: account)
         .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
             for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                 do {
                     let singleCourse: Course = try document.data(as: Course.self)
                     print("===== [2] Append an element ===== \n")
                     coursesArray.append(singleCourse)
                 } catch {
                     print("Place A error... [ FirestoreManager.swift -> UserManager -> getUnapprovedCourses ]")
                 }
                 // print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
             }
             completion(coursesArray)  // <-- here, inside the async function
         }
 }
```

and use it like this:

```
 func getCoursesInfo() {
     let userManager = UserManager()
     print("===== [0] Call the function ===== \n")
     // --- here
     userManager.getUnapprovedCourses(account: account) { results in
         self.coursesArray = results
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getUnapprovedCourses(account: String) -> [Course] {
...
   // return coursesArray
   completion(coursesArray)
}
```

```
func getCoursesInfo() {
    let userManager = UserManager()
    print("===== [0] Call the function ===== \n")

    userManager.getUnapprovedCourses(account: account) { coursesArray in
        self.coursesArray = coursesArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. I would suggest explaining what you are doing and why. FWIW, the `getUnapprovedCourses` appears to be adopting completion handler pattern, but you never gave it a completion closure parameter.